# trying to figure out Framework Television's Maps exercise

Tags: javascript

I am working on an exercise to learn Javascript Maps. I have created a list of chores. Beside each chore, you input a name. Select the button beside the name, and that is supposed to add it to the Map. Once you're done, select a button to display the entire list of chore assignments.

I can't get it to print the list. I'm sure I'm either assigning the name inappropriately to the Map or the .onclick functions are wrong. I've never used those before.

The 'addToMap' ID being referenced is the button that adds the name to the Map. The 'displayList' ID referenced is supposed to display the chore assignment list.

```
<script>
    const ADD = document.getElementById('addToMap');
    const DISPLAY = document.getElementById('displayList');

    let chores = new Map();
    chores.set('Front Room Sweep', 'name');
    chores.set('Back Room Sweep', 'name');
    chores.set('Outside Grounds', 'name');
    chores.set('Clean Toilet', 'name');
    chores.set('Clean Sink', 'name');
    chores.set('Trash Patrol and Supplies', 'name');

    ADD.onclick = function() {
        const name = document.getElementById('name');
        chores.add(name.value);
        name.value = "";
    };

    DISPLAY.onclick = function() {
        let out = "";
        for (let x of chores.values()) {
            out += x[0] + ":  " + x[1];
            out += "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
    }
</script>
```

Instead of showing the list of chores, it simply displays "n:  a" 6 times

Comment: This Javascript doesn't give quite enough info. To be able to see all the code, here is the CodePen - https://codepen.io/rockyclark1/pen/ZgXxrj

Answer (score 0):

`chores.values()` gives you just the values of the map. In this case, the values are a bunch of instances of the string "name". If `x` === "name", then `x[0]` === "n" and `x[1]` === "a"

You probably meant to use `chores.entries()` instead. That way, each time through the loop, `x` will be an array, with element 0 of the array being the key (eg, "Front Room Sweep") and element 1 being the value (eg, "name").

```
DISPLAY.onclick = function() {
    let out = "";
    for (let x of chores.entries()) {
        out += x[0] + ":  " + x[1];
        out += "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: That was a big step in the right direction. It will now display the appropriate chore, but gives 'name' as the value. It's obviously not pulling in the text that is input into that field. For example, it would display " Front Room Sweep:  name"

Comment: `but gives 'name' as the value` The second parameter to `chores.set` is the value. In the code you provided, all the values are explicitly set to the string `"name"`. What are you expecting?

Comment: Ya, the fact that you can't see my HTML makes this tricky. There is a text input field. Whatever text is input into the field is supposed to display there. Here's the CodePen link - https://codepen.io/rockyclark1/pen/ZgXxrj